# Why does LINQ send sp_executesql instead of directly executing the SQL?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

For eaxmple, LINQ to SQL is sending the following:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'SELECT [t0].[HomeID], 
  [t0].[Bedrooms], 
  [t0].[ImageURL], 
  [t0].[Price], 
  [t0].[Available], 
  [t0].[Description]
FROM 
  [dbo].[Homes] AS [t0]
WHERE 
  ([t0].[Description] LIKE @p0) AND 
    ([t0].[Available] = @p1) AND 
    ([t0].[Price] >= @p2) AND ([t0].[Price] <= @p3)
ORDER BY 
  [t0].[Price] DESC',
N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int',
@p0=N'%private%',
@p1=1,
@p2=200000,
@p3=750000
```

Why does it use sp_executesql?

Comment: OP you should clarify what you mean a little - I take it you're watching through SQL Profiler and see calls flowing by.  I interpret your question as "why does L2S use sp_executesql rather than send the contained statements directly".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This notation allows the runtime compiled TSQL statement to be re-used with different parameters; i.e. the statement only gets compiled once which improves efficiency.

Comment: Execute uses the same statement cache with parameterized queries.

Comment: Also, this way it's more secure against SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT, oops did I say paramterization instead of parameter replacement, thanks stephbu**

sp_executesql is preferred over execute because it supports parameter substitution, and tends to perform more efficiently.

Comment: Execute is just as parameterizable, so parameterization isn't it.  What data says it performs "more efficiently"  Its at least the same cost.

Comment: It may have been more technically correct to say parameter substitution rather than parameterization, as for the efficiency I invite you to check out the following link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580.aspx as additional information about Execute supporting the same parameterized statement caching strategies.

Comment: The article is talking about the EXECUTE tsql statement.  The OP is wondering why sp_executesql is being sent rather than sending the "inner" statement directly (parameters and all).

Comment: Yeah I guess I should qualify mine a bit better too :)  SQLExecDirect through OLEDB/ODBC is just as a parameterizable.  Unless there was more than a single statement being sent - it doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is, at least partially, so that you get query plan reuse.  It could put the parameters inline, which means that every time you run the query with different parameters the analyzer sees it as a different query and reparses it.  But since it's executed this way, the query plan is cached and it can just plug in the new variables each time you run it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is a performance solution. Execution plans in SQL are cached even for direct queries.

I do think it is a security solution for sql injection.

However if you try to use traces that use Linq to SQL in the Database Engine Tuning Advisor the sp_execute is not interpeted by the Tuning Advisor, I would like to turn it off. SQL injection can also be detected in the Linq To Sql statements / framework (the code) why would you even try to send invalid data to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that it also provides protection from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because of parameterization.  Can't really complain about that one...

Comment: Not according to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx - "Run time-compiled Transact-SQL statements can expose applications to malicious attacks, such as SQL injection."

Comment: This isn't a reason to use sp_executesql tho'.  Parameterization is available on the SqlExecDirect calls through OLE/DB and ODBC too.

Comment: @Adamski - of course it does.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx.  "LINQ to SQL avoids such injection by using SqlParameter in queries."

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question.  
This isn't really answer but an exploration of the reasoning already given by other answers.  Feel free to update this "answer"

The obvious answer would have been "`parameterized query cache`".  However parameters could just as easily been bound when the statement was executed directly *and* still get cached.

Syntax and details in this **MSDN** article...

[msdn_microsoft_ms175580](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580(SQL.90).aspx)

Performance claims I doubt without data since the cache appears to be the same for both direct and sp_execsql'd queries.

So if it's not those - what is it?